# Is their an easy way to use the formula from a ggplot in a markdown table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to have the same mathematical formula for both a plot (`ggplot2::ggplot`) and markdown table(`knitr::kable`) in R. Below is how I would add a formula to a plot.

```
# Basic R scatter plot with "wt" replaced by a mathematical expression for the x-axis-label
g1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + xlab(expression(beta[0]))
g1
xl <- g1$labels$x
xl
```

Can I auto-convert/**parse** the xl "beta[0]" expression to markdown "$$\beta_0$$"?
... e.g. for only a manual conversion table below

```
xl <- "$$\\beta_0$$"  
knitr::kable(cbind(var = xl,mean = mean(g1$data$wt)))
```

Or is their an easier way to use the formula from a ggplot in a markdown table?

Comment: You can do the converse with the **latex2exp** package: `lab <- "$\\beta_0$"` then `xlab(TeX(lab))`.